# Retap event on TabbedPage

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I am trying to capture a retap event for a `TabbedPage` on UWP.

From [this page](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/90796/tabbedpage-event-on-tab-click-or-refresh-tab-when-same-tab-is-clicked), I can see that you need to create a custom renderer. When I try to use `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.TabbedPageRenderer`, I can't find any appropriate event to subscribe to.

I have tried the `Tapped` and `Focused` events, but they do not seem to work as I expect.

How do you detect if a tab is re-tapped on UWP?

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
public class TabbedPageCustomRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer
{
    private TabbedHomePage _page;
    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            _page = (TabbedHomePage)e.NewElement;
        }
        else
        {
            _page = (TabbedHomePage)e.OldElement;
        }

        //_page.Focused += _page_Focused;
        //this.Control.Tapped += Control_Tapped;

        // what should I subscribe to?
    }

    private async void _page_Focused(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.FocusEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_page?.CurrentPage?.Navigation != null && _page.CurrentPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count > 0)
        {
            await _page.CurrentPage.Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
        }
    }

    private async void Control_Tapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_page?.CurrentPage?.Navigation != null && _page.CurrentPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count > 0)
        {
            await _page.CurrentPage.Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answer from DavidS, here is the code I used, which also handles icons in the UWP tab:

```
// this is C# 7, so will only work with a recent c# compiler
public class TabbedPageCustomRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer
{
    private Xamarin.Forms.Page _prevPage;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        Control.Tapped += Control_Tapped;
        _prevPage = Control.SelectedItem as Xamarin.Forms.Page;
    }

    private async void Control_Tapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // replace 'TabbedHomePage' with whatever your page type is with the tabs
        if (!(this.Element is TabbedHomePage))
            return;

        switch (e.OriginalSource)
        {
            case Image image when image.Parent is StackPanel:
                {
                    var sp = (StackPanel)image.Parent;

                    var tb = sp.Children.Where(c => c is TextBlock).FirstOrDefault() as TextBlock;

                    await HandleRetab(tb);
                    break;
                }
            case TextBlock tb:
                {
                    await HandleRetab(tb);
                    break;
                }
            default:
                break;
        }

        async Task HandleRetab(TextBlock tb)
        {
            if (tb == null)
                return;

            var newPage = tb.DataContext as Xamarin.Forms.Page;
            if (newPage == _prevPage &&
                tb.Name == "TabbedPageHeaderTextBlock")
            {
                // do your thing here, a tab retap happened, like:
                await newPage.Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
            }

            _prevPage = newPage;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that no, as far as I can tell, you can't easily detect tab retap/reselect on UWP, at least without digging into the Xamarin.Forms source code a bit to see how they implemented the uWP TabbedPageRenderer.

Here is how I implemented it:

```
public class MainTabPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer
{
    private Xamarin.Forms.Page _prevPage;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        Control.Tapped += Control_Tapped;
        _prevPage = Control.SelectedItem as Xamarin.Forms.Page;
    }

    private async void Control_Tapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var src = e.OriginalSource as TextBlock;
        if (src != null
             && src.Name == "TabbedPageHeaderTextBlock"
             && Element is TabReselectDemo.MainPage)
        {
            var newPage = src.DataContext as Xamarin.Forms.Page;
            if (newPage == _prevPage)
            {
                // do your thing here, a tab retap happened, like:
                await newPage.Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
            }
            _prevPage = newPage;
        }
    }
}
```

The TabbedPageHeaderTextBlock is part of the internals of the UWP renderer.  Given that it's not documented, this isn't ideal as it could theoretically change on a future version of Xamarin.Forms, but it has been stable for a while.

That should be enough to solve it for you, but more details here: https://criticalhittech.com/2017/09/25/tab-reselection-in-xamarin-forms-part-2/.

Comment: Thanks! It worked great. I updated your code to handle icons in the UWP tab in another answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your explanation I have update your code, hope this will help:

```
public class TabbedPageCustomRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer
{
    private TabbedHomePage _page;
    bool isRetap = false;
    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            _page = (TabbedHomePage)e.NewElement;
        }
        else
        {
            _page = (TabbedHomePage)e.OldElement;
        }

        //_page.Focused += _page_Focused;
        this.Control.Tapped += Control_Tapped;

        // what should I subscribe to?
    }

    private async void _page_Focused(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.FocusEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_page?.CurrentPage?.Navigation != null && _page.CurrentPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count > 0)
        {
            await _page.CurrentPage.Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
        }
    }

    private async void Control_Tapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isRetap && _page?.CurrentPage?.Navigation != null && _page.CurrentPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count > 0)
        {
            await _page.CurrentPage.Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
        }
        isRetap = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem with the `Tapped` event is that it affects not only the actual tab, but also the entire `ContentPage`. Is there a way to limit this to just the tab itself?